# unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpException' occurred in System.dll

Tags: c#, smtp

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: Failure sending mail.
im getting above error when executing:

```
           var smtp = new SmtpClient
            {

                Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                Port = 25, (tried with 587 also)
                EnableSsl = true,
                DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential(mail_From, from_Password)
                //,
                //Timeout = 200
            };
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;
            message.Subject = "DeleteDuplicateDevicesReport";
            message.Body = bodyStructure;
            message.From = new MailAddress(mail_From.ToString());
            message.To.Add(mail_To);
            smtp.Send(message);
            connection.Close();
```

this will send the message through smtp server

Comment: What's ado.net has to do with this? Please [edit] your question, remove that tag and add language tag instead.

Comment: done the required changes, please help me out now

Comment: Not sure what causing it but this article can help. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/send-email-using-gmail-smtp

Comment: Not sure if it's a dupe, but did you read this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13506623/smtp-exception-failure-sending-mail